# How do I find out what view file is being used in codeigniter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

In a nutshell I'm updating some code that uses CodeIgniter and I'm wasting a lot of time just tracing the code's controllers to find out what views are being used.

Is there an easy way to find out what view is being used and possibly what controller is calling them.

I know you'd usually just go to the uri and figure it out from there, but the previous programmer used some really complicated regex in his routing.

I'm looking for a tracing tool that does something like ASP.NET tracing or maybe a tool similar to .NET's [Glimpse](http://getglimpse.com/)

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Get in contact with the previous programmer, let yourself explain/document the routing system she/he has implemented and things should be just clear then.

Comment: Show us his complicated regex routing and a sample url.
Is his routing handled in .htaccess through mod-rewrite or is it in `config/routes.php`?

Comment: wouldn't have posted here if I had either of those things. the previous programmer went awol and we've no idea how to get in touch with him. current code is understandable/traceable but it gets a bit tedious having to look through the code everytime I load a page and that's time I don't have. I just want to know what view is being used by the current page. If there's an easier way to do this then my current method, I'd be happy to hear it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is now a version of Glimpse for PHP.

You may be able to createba plugin for it: http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2011/08/02/A-client-side-Glimpse-to-your-PHP-application.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Enable [profiler](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/profiling.html). `controller_info` section should help you out.

[Here is example how to enable ir globally.](http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/151968/#915515)